# VS2012 driver package using wrong output directory in x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, driver

This appears to be a bug in VS2012 but I'm wondering if anyone has a workaround or can explain what's wrong. I followed this page for creating a simple KMDF driver in vs2012 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Before building, I set the output directory for the driver package project to "$(SolutionDir)Output\$(ConfigurationName)\", the main difference being the addition of "Output" to the path.

When I build targeting Win32 it works fine, everything goes where I expect it to. However, when I build targeting x64, the output goes to "$(SolutionDir)$(ConfigurationName)\" instead. No matter what I enter for the output directory, it always starts at the SolutionDir.

When I'm selecting the Output Directory, if I click on Macros, I can see that OutDir is where the output is actually going, it does not match what I have specified for "Output Directory" in the project properties. Is there something else that is overriding OutDir? I've tried setting OutDir in the .vcxproj file but it still behaves the same.

Comment: A simple explanation is that you only changed the setting for the Win32 configuration and forgot to do it again for the x64 configuration.

Comment: No, I have the output setting set for both Win32 and x64.

Comment: I am seeing this issue for both Win32 and x64 (I can't even get it working on Win32) on Visual Studio 2013.  Has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having this issue; I have found a fix for myself.

You'll need to manually edit the project file (.vcxproj file).

You'll find this line:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
```

Move the property group that contains the OutDir definition right below that line, as in the following:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <OutDir>$(SolutionDir)outbin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)\</OutDir>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)outbin\$(Configuration)\$(Platform)</OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

On my setup, the Microsoft.Cpp.props is overwritting those paths, so I need that to be included first, then overwrite what is configured in there.